# Watch OS - App Transport security

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2, ios9.2, xcode7.3

I am using Xcode 7.3. I have added App Transport Security Settings and set Allow Arbitary Loads to yes in watchkit extension info.plist.And want to play audio from an http link [sound source](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1bsoqCzbqxj) using watchkit **MediaPlayerController** But the apple watch keeps throwing the error "**The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security requires the use of a secure connection**".

[image: Watchkit extension info.plist]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/presentMediaPlayerControllerWithURL:options:completion) the audio content must be store to a https server. Otherwise need to download the file manually.